# I have a list of apartment numbers, how do I display an array of email addresses?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a worksheet that has apartment numbers that is organized with one person per row, unit, first, last, and email in separate columns. I want to find a formula that will reference a list of the units, then display email addresses for each of the people associated with that unit.

Basically, I want to print an array that will return values from the same column in different rows based on an intersected datapoint.

What I have now is:

```
=IF(Table1[Front door]=Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$J2:$J74,"")
```

which I CSE. This gives me the first instance of the intersection but not all.

Comment: If you select only one cell then CSE, you will get only the first value (assuming your formula was correct). But also, it is preferable to make you column arrays of equal size. Currently you have 3 such arrays each with its own size.

Comment: I have a table on sheet 1 that I am referencing the front door number, and a column on sheet 2 that I am cross-referencing. I want to print all emails associated with this front door, one per cell in the row adjacent so that I can mail merge it. Right now it is just printing the first instance of this over and over in each row